# Saving Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am able to save the value of one input on my web app, but now I am trying to save multiple input values. I want to save the user's email, phone, city, etc. How do I set that up in my javascript function that is linked to firebase? What I have currently is only saving the studio name. I have provided my code and a screenshot of the database and web app inputs below:

Firebase Real-Time Database:
[image: Firebase Real-Time Database]

User Input Screenshot:
[image]

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!---Required meta tags--->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/editprofile.css">
        <script>"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"</script>
        <!---Required meta tags--->
    
        <!---Like Button JavaScript--->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f6dcf461c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!---Like Button JavaScript--->
    
        <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
        
        <title>StudioPick</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item2">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <form class="container py-5 h-100" id="studioForm">
            <div class="container">
                <main>
                  <div class="py-5 text-center">
                    <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="/docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="72" height="57">
                    <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
                    <p class="lead">Here is where you can change your profile settings and update your personal information.</p>
                  </div>
              
                  <div class="row g-5">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
                      <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                        <span>Your Profile Picure</span>
                      </h4>
                      
                      <div class="profile-img">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" id="profile-pic" src="Images/placeholder.png" alt="">
                      </div>
              
                      <form class="card p-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="uploadBtn">Upload</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                      <h4 class="mb-3">Personal Information</h4>
                      <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                        <div class="row g-3">
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ownerFirstName" placeholder="John" value="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Valid first name is required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ownerLastName" placeholder="Doe" value="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Valid last name is required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please enter a valid email address for updates.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please enter your address.
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="phoneNumber" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Phone number required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                            <label for="country" class="form-label">Country</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="country" required="">
                              <option value="">Choose...</option>
                              <option>United States</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please select a valid country.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="state" class="form-label">State</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="state" required="">
                              <option value="">Choose...</option>
                              <option>California</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please provide a valid state.
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              City required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="zip" class="form-label">Zip</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="12345" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Zip code required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="studio" class="form-label">Studio Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studioName" placeholder="GOOD Records" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Studio name required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
              
                        <hr class="my-4">
              
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>
              
                        <div class="my-3">
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input id="credit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked="" required="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="credit">Credit card</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input id="debit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" required="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="debit">Debit card</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input id="paypal" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" required="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="paypal">PayPal</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
              
                        <div class="row gy-3">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="cc-name" class="form-label">Name on card</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-name" placeholder="" required="">
                            <small class="text-muted">Full name as displayed on card</small>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Name on card is required
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="cc-number" class="form-label">Credit card number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Credit card number is required
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="cc-expiration" class="form-label">Expiration</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-expiration" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Expiration date required
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="cc-cvv" class="form-label">CVV</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Security code required
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
              
                        <hr class="my-4">
              
                        <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" onclick="save()", onclick="submitStu()", window.location.href='editprofile.html'">Update Info</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </main>
              
                <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
                  <p class="mb-1">© 2022 StudioPick.</p>
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </footer>
              </div>
        </form>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <!---Javascript--->
    <script src="Javascript/editprofile.js"></script>
    <!---Javascript--->
    
    <!----More Bootstrap--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----More Bootstrap--->
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


//Creating sets in database
firebase.database().ref("/Studiopick/studios").child("users").update({
    purpose : "adding user"
    
});

//Save information
function save(){
    studioName = document.getElementById("studioName").value;
    firebase.database().ref("/Studiopick/studios/users").child(studioName).update({
        email : email,
        phoneNumber : phoneNumber,
        city : city,
        purpose : "adding user"
    
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript code looks correct for the Firebase part. However you don't define the values of `email`, `phoneNumber`, etc... You should do as follows:

```
const studioName = document.getElementById("studioName").value;
const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
// ...
firebase.database().ref("/Studiopick/studios/users")...
```

In addition, you should adapt the following line:

```
<button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" onclick="save()", onclick="submitStu()", window.location.href='editprofile.html'">Update Info</button>
```

Firstly, you call two different methods with the `onClick` event: you should have only one event.

Secondly, your button is of type `submit`. As you can see in the [W3 specification on button types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element), with this type your form is going to be submitted. What may happen in this case is that the form is submitted before the Firebase `update()` method is triggered. You should change it to `type="button"`, in such a way that only the (unique) `onClick` event is triggered.

Comment: nothing happens. I didn't get an error or anything in the console either

Comment: it works with the original formula, but whenever I add more values, nothing gets populated in my database with no errors

Answer (score 0):

You can select all value and add them to your array that is send like so :

```js
const form = document.getElementById(yourForm);
let values = [];
const inputs = form.getElementByTagName("input");
for (let i in inputs) {
    values[i] = inputs[i];
}
console.log(values);
```